# Retrieving value from dynamically generated elements using Jquery Name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui

I have a mvc cshtml form where I am generating multiple rows using following syntax :

```
foreach (var i in Model)
   {            
    <td>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].SFDCID, new { id = "SFDCID", @class ="SFDCID" })
    </td>
   }
```

This is resulting HTML snippet like :

```
 <input class="SFDCID" id="SFDCID" name="[0].SFDCID" type="text" value="">
    <input class="SFDCID" id="SFDCID" name="[1].SFDCID" type="text" value="">
.....
.....
```

Now I want to check if user has entered values in all SFDCID field then only the form submit should happen else should throw validation message.

For that I am trying to access the value using its name attribute & have written following code:

```
           for (var i = 0; i <= totalNumberOfRows; i++) {

                var elementName = '[' + i + '].SFDCID';    
                if ($("[name = elementName]").val() == "" || 
                                     $("[name = elementName]").val() == undefined) 
                {
                        ConsolidatedErrorMsg = "SFDC ID is a Mandatory field.";
    }
}
```

I have tried with class, id & name as selector to get the value, but in first 2 case its only working for 1st row. 
With Name selector its working for both name if I hard code the element name like '[0].SFDCID' & '[1].SFDCID' but when I am substituting i with 0 & 1, its not working.

Kindly help me to rectify any syntax error I have in this selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("[name = elementName]")` is actually selecting all elements with the name of, literally, `elementName`. You actually need to escape square brackets and concat the value you have constructed:

```
var elementName = '\\[' + i + '\\].SFDCID';
$("[name='" + elementName + "']")
```

Even better approach would be to use *ends with* selector:

```
$("[name$='\\.SFDCID']").each(function() {
    // this here refers to the found element
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() === "" || typeof($this.val()) === undefined) {
        ConsolidatedErrorMsg = "SFDC ID is a Mandatory field.";
    }
})
```

A couple of side notes. Please remove `id = "SFDCID"` bit, as duplicated IDs on the page may lead to inconsistent behavior. And consider using built-in ways to validate required fields.

Comment: Thanks Andrei for pointing out the flaws here. I wanted to use built in Required field validator, but this SFDCID filed changes its behavior (mandatory or optional) based on some other property values.  I could have used RequiredIf attribute or by overriding Validate() method, but those approaches do not provide client side validation option. So finally had to choose the jquery way of validation.

Comment: If you know any better way of built in validators, please help me giving the clue about that. Thx in advance.

Comment: @Biki, A `[RequiredIf]` attribute does provide client side validation if you have implement `IClientValidatable`. Have a look at the [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) although its easier enough to write your own - refer [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: @ Stephen : +1 for the links which is helpful to implement client side validations too.  Thx